# How to compare randomly generated cards in a java card program?

Tags: java

I am a first time Java student and I ran into a small issue when creating a program that randomly selects two cards out of a standard 52 card deck. I am trying to create a statement that will compare if the two cards share the same rank or the same suit. When I tried creating an if statement to do so, I got an error saying I cannot compare two identical expressions. I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight on what to do. This is my code:

```
package Assignment3;

public class HouseOfCards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = new int[52];
        String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        String[] ranks = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i;

        for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

            int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
            int temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[index];
            deck[index] = temp;
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
            String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
            System.out.println(rank + " of " + suit);
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt was:

```
if (suit==suit) 
    System.out.println("Cards share the same suit"); 
else 
    System.out.println("Cards do not share the same suit"); 
if (rank==rank) 
    System.out.println("Cards share the same rank"); 
else 
    System.out.println("Card do not share the same rank");
```

Comment: Can you include your attempt?

Comment: if (suit==suit)
   System.out.println("Cards share the same suit");
  else
   System.out.println("Cards do not share the same suit");
  if (rank==rank)
   System.out.println("Cards share the same rank");
  else
   System.out.println("Card do not share the same rank");

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the first 2 cards to check whether they have the same suit or rank, you can use the code below. You don't need the loop, you can just compare the cards with index 0 and 1 from your array:

```
if (deck[0] / 13 == deck[1] / 13) {
   System.out.println("Cards share the same suit");
} else { 
   System.out.println("Cards do not share the same suit");
}
if (deck[0] % 13 == deck[1] % 13) {
    System.out.println("Cards share the same rank"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("Card do not share the same rank");
}
```

Comment: Instead of `for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {` loop.

Comment: But don't I need that for loop to print out the two random cards?

Comment: You can leave the loop to print the cards then and do the comparison after.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much for your help. It worked now :)